# How to use "Buildings as Props" plugin?

Tags: simcity-4

I have ([downloaded](https://www.simcityplaza.de/index.php/tools-und-andere-downloads/offizielle-downloads/file/446-buildings-as-props-von-maxis)) and installed the "Buildings as Props" plugin by Maxis. How do I get this working in SimCity 4?

Comment: I'm getting a "potential risk" warning using your link.

Comment: @Joachim the hosting site isn't using HTTPS. Bit surprising in 2022.

Comment: Worse, it's using a certificate issued to a completely different site. I wouldn't download _anything_ from there.

Comment: @Joachim When I entered the page it just was HTTP. No certificate issue.

Comment: @MiG It's an old website that's just sort-of continued until now. I don't think it gets any attention by the makers anymore, just by the users.

Answer (score 1):

They [seem](https://community.simtropolis.com/sc4-maxis-files/) to be called "Buildings as props".
They contain .dat files (database files), and have to go into the [/Plugin folder](https://www.sc4devotion.com/forums/index.php?msg=317192):

> `\Program Files\Maxis\SimCity 4\Plugins`
>
> - All subfolders are recursively loaded first
> - This is the plugins folder for Maxis' official landmarks

- The folder `Program Files` can usually be found on disk `C:\`.
- As SimCity 4 was released in 2003, it's probably not a 64-bit program, so I guess that on Windows Vista/8/10 the folder `\Program Files` will be `\Program Files (x86)`.
- You can retain the folder structure from the downloaded ZIP files.

Comment: I didn't want to know where to put it, I want to know how to use it in-game to manually place those props (my dad says he's done that before). I have already put it in the plugins folder but I don't know how to open its menu if it even has one. My dad says it was something with the Ctrl+X input mask but he doesn't know anymore what to enter there. Or is it a hotkey that you have to press to activate/open it?